# How do I add a dropdown column to my collection in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have a gallery connected to an Excel table. I want to add some of the gallery columns to a collection.
I am doing-

`ClearCollect(Attgallery,ShowColumns(Gallery3.AllItems,"Name","Language","Mentor","Type",Dropdownatt.Selected.Value));`

The last column that I am adding here is a dropdown value which is giving me the error. The dropdown is a new column which was not present in the Excel table. How do I add it to the collection?

Edit: I tried changing my code.

```
ClearCollect(Attgallery,ShowColumns(Gallery3.AllItems,"Name","Language","Mentor","Type"));
ClearCollect(Finalcollection,AddColumns(Attgallery,"Attendance",Dropdownatt.Selected));
```

Now the collection is getting created, but from the dropdown values only the last value that was selected is being assigned to every row of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that shows an approach with ForAll:

```
clear( YourCollection );
ForAll(
  Gallery.AllItems,
  Collect( 
    YourCollection,
    ThisRecord.Dropdownatt.selected,
    ....
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-forall

This links gives some information. Basically you should collect every row with it's associated dropdown value. ForAll is useful for this.

Comment: I tried 
`Clear(Attdata);
ForAll(Gallery5.AllItems,
Collect(Attdata,
ThisRecord.Dropdown1.Selected,
"Name","Badge","Manager","Language","Type"));` It creates an empty collection with 5 rows.

Comment: You created empty values indeed. "Name" and "Badge" are meaningless in this context, it should be of type record, defined as: { Name: ThisItem.Name, Badge: ThisItem.Badge } and so on.